# I am getting an error in the JSX while calling a function inside it

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
<Accordion>
 {
   Object.keys(this.state.comparedResult.sourceNotMatched).map((item, index) => (
     <AccordionTab header={"PAGE " + item} key={index}>
       <Item.Group divided >
         {
           this.state.comparedResult.sourceNotMatched[item].map((fields, i) => (
             <>
               <Item key={i}>
                   <span className='reviewCardErrorBody'>{fields}</span>
               </Item>
               {this.isRemoved()}
               <buttonNew label="removed" className="p-button-danger" />
             </>
           ))
         }
       </Item.Group>
     </AccordionTab>
   ))
 }
</Accordion>
```

./src/components/CodeComparison.js
Line 426:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error

Comment: Please type the full code to see where the error does, paste the function you used here beginning from input until to call the function in app.js

Comment: Make sure you are returning your component, Please include complete code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are utilizing function incorrectly since you did not include the event when this function is invoked, such as onclick, onload, onkeydown, and so on. And then apply this method to an HTML element, like as

```
<button className="btn" onClick={() => this. isRemoved()}>test</button>
```

or

```
<buttonNew label="removed" className="p-button-danger" isRemoved={this.isRemoved} />

<button className="btn" onClick={() => prpos. isRemoved()}>test</button>
```

Comment: No, Its now my use case here, Based on the return of that function I need to display that button. Which is I need a true or false value to display that button. Just forget about the button.

Comment: { this.isRemoved ? <buttonNew label="removed" className="p-button-danger" /> : null }
I hope this work for you

Comment: @muhammed, the way you have mentioned is works, Thanks